# Book with aliens who use telekinesis called castling

Tags: story-identification

I read part of one of my dads books when I was young (probably around 1982-1983).  The bit I remember is about an alien boy in a competition to fetch a goblet at the end of a forest. He forgets his telekinetic ability and runs to get it whilst his opponent "castles" the goblet, using telekinesis to fetch it.